# Android app doesn't show colors properly?

Tags: android, colors

I tried some Material Design stuff based on the Google's design principles and I wanted to add some "Material colors". I chose the colors from Google's material color palette but my device showed the colors MUCH brighter than on the site. After that I picked up some colors from materialpalette.com but I had the same problem. I tested this with an Android 4.2 device.

Comment: If you're using a Samsung phone(especially one with an AMOLED display), let me tell you, Samsung's displays have a tendency to artificially bump up colors, in order to make things look a lot more vibrant. I still don't understand why they do it.

Comment: Yes, I have a Samsung phone with AMOLED display. So I can't do anything against this color issue. :/

Comment: No... But rest assured, it'll look fine on other devices.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Different colors rendering is due to phone hardware. Deal with it.